# Angular Flexlayout LayoutGap not margin in viewPort

Tags: angular, angular-flex-layout

Hi I have a problem with Angular and FlexLayout. I do not understand how to adjust the input to mat-card-content in different views. It's perfect the flex to fit the change the size of the viewport.

In really need remove margin y ajust to the container card.

[StackBlitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fk78jr)

```
<mat-card>
<mat-card-content>
    <form [formGroup]="grupo" (ngSumit)="insertar()">
        <p>NEW TASACION</p>
        <div class="input-row" fxLayout="row wrap" fxLayoutGap="25px">
            <mat-form-field appearance="standard" fxFlex="calc(25% - 25px)" fxFlex.xs="0px">
                <mat-label>Codigo Coordinación</mat-label>
                <input matInput type="text" placeholder="Codigo de Coordinación" formControlName="codigoCoordinacion">
                <mat-icon matSuffix>description</mat-icon>
            </mat-form-field>
            <mat-form-field appearance="standard" fxFlex="calc(50% - 25px)" fxFlex.xs="0px">
                <mat-label>Fecha Tasación</mat-label>
                <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker1" placeholder="Fecha de Tasación" formControlName="date">
                <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="
                 picker1"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
                <mat-datepicker #picker1></mat-datepicker>
            </mat-form-field>
            <mat-form-field appearance="standard" fxFlex="calc(25% - 25px)" fxFlex.xs="0px">
                <mat-label>AAA Coordinación</mat-label>
                <input matInput type="text" placeholder="Codigo de Coordinación">
                <mat-icon matSuffix>description</mat-icon>
            </mat-form-field>

        </div>

        <div class="button-row" fxLayout="row wrap" fxLayoutGap="25px" fxLayout.xs="column" fxLayoutAlign="end">
            <button mat-flat-button color="primary" [disabled]="!grupo.valid">Grabar</button>
        </div>
        <!-- <div class="button-row" fxLayout="row wrap" fxLayout.xs="column" fxLayoutGap="20px" fxLayoutGap.xs="0px" fxLayoutAlign="end">
            <button mat-flat-button color="primary" [disabled]="!grupo.valid">Grabar</button>
        </div> -->
    </form>
</mat-card-content>
```

[image]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to StackOverflow! I don't really understand what it is you're wanting to accomplish. I see included your code, image, and demo (nice work!). In the image, you highlight the `margin: 25px` with the red rectangle. Are you wanting to remove that so there is no margin? I'm not totally clear on what your goal is...

Comment: @Narm thanks my friends, is my firts post sorry, Im from Peru. 

In really need remove margin y ajust to the container  card.